# How to catch error when Firestore collection already exists?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, try-catch

Right now my app is crashing when a collection already exists in Firebase Firestore. I want to catch this error when it happens, but my current implementation doesn't catch anything as the `addSnapshotListener()` method does not throw any error.

**Current Code**

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
        
        do {
            try db.collection(chatName).addSnapshotListener { (Query, Error) in
                if Error != nil || Query?.documents != nil {
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Chat Name Already Exists", message: "This chat name already exists, try again with a different name", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
                        alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)}))
                    AllChatsViewController().present(alert, animated: true)
                    completion()
                }
                else {
                    self.addChatToProfile(withName: chatName) {
                        completion()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Chat Name Already Exists", message: "This chat name already exists, try again with a different name", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) in
                alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)}))
            AllChatsViewController().present(alert, animated: true)
            completion()
        }
```

**Error After App Crashes**

> Thread 1: "Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments, but  has 0"

How can I catch this error so I can display an UIAlertController with the error?

Comment: We don't know what the `chatName` string contains. Can you include that in the question? You may just want to add a `print(chatName)` right before the firebase call to see what it is. Also only capitalize *Class* and *Structure* names. *var*'s should always be lowercased to avoid confusion. So instead of `Query, Error`, it should be `query, error`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a different approach.

To test if a collection exists, read that collection by name and determine if there are any documents via snapshot.count equals 0

The gotcha here is that a collection could have a large amount of data and there's no reason to read all of that in or attach a listener so we need to use a known field within that collection to limit the results.

I would suggest a function with a closure that returns true if the collection exists, false if not and then take action based on that result.

You'll need the name of the collection you want to test and then the name of a known field within that collection to query for to limit the results.

The field name is important in that if the collection has 1M documents, you don't want to read them all in - you just want to read one and .orderBy with a limit will do that.

So here's a calling function

```
func checkCollection() {
    self.doesCollectionExist(collectionName: "test_collection", fieldName: "msg", completion: { isEmpty in
        if isEmpty == true {
            print("collection does not exist")
        } else {
            print("collection found!")
        }
    })
}
```

and then the function that checks to see if the collection exists by reading one document and returns false if not, true if it does.

```
func doesCollectionExist(collectionName: String, fieldName: String, completion: @escaping ( (Bool) -> Void ) ) {
    let ref = self.db.collection(collectionName)
    let query = ref.order(by: fieldName).limit(toLast: 1)
    query.getDocuments(completion: { snapshot, error in
        if let err = error {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            return
        }
        
        if snapshot!.count == 0 {
            completion(true)
        } else {
            completion(false)
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That error doesn't have anything to do with a collection not existing  The error suggests that `chatName` is an empty string, which is an invalid parameter.  Instead of catching an error, you should instead first validate that `chatName` is a valid collection name string before sending it to the Firestore API.

If you query a collection that doesn't exist, you won't get that error message at all.  Instead, you will simply get no documents in the result set.

Comment: ```chatName``` is not empty though, the full string is printing after adding a print statement

Comment: Then, whatever it is, it's not valid.  You should check it before you pass it to the API.  The rules for names of collections and documents are here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields

Comment: I revised the question, the problem is the collection already exists. Basically, I want to check to see if the collection exists. If it does, I want to display a UIAlertController, but if it doesn't, I want to create a collection under this name.

Comment: You really should also show the specific value of `chatName` that doesn't work the way you expect.  There is no operation to check if a collection exists.  You have to actually query it and get a document out of it to know that it exists.  Your query is failing because the value of `chatName` is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

you will make something like this:

```
     Firestore.firestore().collection(chatName).addSnapshotListener { (query, error) in
          if let error = error {
           //in this part you have the error, do something like present alert with error or something you want
           print(error)
           }
          // in this part the success
```

Comment: in this case usually not use try catch, instead use the line that I show you and work well, but is just a recommendation.